# String manipulation for latex

Tags: bash, sh

I am trying to write a long expression with numbers and strings in a certain way so that it could be fed to latex. A short part of the expression is like

```
exp = 176*X*Y/9 + (1408*X*Y^2)/9 + 23/10 + ...
```

The desired output is

```
exp = X Y (\frac{176}{9}) + X Y^2 (\frac{1408}{9}) + \frac{23}{10} + ...
```

While I know how to do for pure numbers like the last terms 23/10 (thanks to stackoverflow ), the cases where it is mixed with string is unclear.
The actual case is more complicated with more strings like Zeta[2], Log[p] etc., however a hint could be useful.

Comment: `I am trying to write a long expression ...` `The desired output is`. Just write the output then? Are you really trying to write a long expression? Or you are trying to write a bash script that will transform from one input to another? If you know how to do it for pure numbers, can you post some code how to it? What have you tried? You need to find the number not string in multiplication and use it to place inside the `\frac` part.  Have you read [converting-c-into-latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/347463/converting-c-like-math-expressions-to-latex)?

Comment: why not write it as `176/9*X*Y ...` ?  So that you can trivially transform?

Comment: @KamilCuk Yes. I am trying to transform a long mathematica output into a latex form. I have mentioned that for pure numbers I found something like this: sed -E 's|([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)|\\frac{\1}{\2}|g' file

Comment: @karakfa yes the cases 176/9*X*Y ... would be trivial with the above code. But my expression has different form like (176*X*Y)/9 from mathematica. I do not know now how to change that. However I will look at this.

Comment: So I would go with dynamic programming. Concentrate on creating a function which would convert a `number*X*Y/number` into `X*Y*number/number`. Are all expressions in the form you posted? Can they be grouped and parsed separately when using a `+` sign as a separator? If not, you are left with writing a very smart parser, which probably is simpler in mathematica then in bash.

Comment: I would look into this. And probably `number/number*X*Y` would be the way I should look as @karakfa also suggested. However from bash side, I was thinking if I could separate `(1408*X*Y^2)/9` as `1408/9` and `X*Y^2`. There are some examples to separate numbers from string, however those dont work since I have something like `XY^2` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Mathematica function

```
TeXForm[exp]
```

will give you the expression you need.

Comment: TexForm is not very efficient when you try to convert a very long expression. Imagine part of the expression where numerator has a lots of \frac{}{} and the whole numerator is divided by some small denominator. It will look horrible. I have already tried that. TexForm might be useful for simple small expressions but not for a a very huge and complicated expressions which I am encountering now.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, either the expression is complex and so is its latex representation or it can be simplified.  If it can be simplified Mathematica can do it with `Simplify[exp]`.

Comment: Unfortunately I can not post the full expression and I have only given a piece just to make it clear on what I want to do. I am talking about expressions with thousands of lines after simplification. TeXForm is not the right choice. Moreover I dont know how much of control one has while using TexForm. Meaning may be there could be fancy hack and a better way to use TeXForm!! Not sure. But my experience with just TexForm[expression] is not a good idea.

Comment: Sorry, expressions with thousands of lines is beyond my comprehension level.  I would guess it should be for most of the other mortals as well.  Good luck with your task!

Comment: I can give you links of scientific papers with such huge lines. But this is not the issue. Even with a few hundred lines or less TexForm is not good. Probably `number/number*X*Y` would be the best way to go!